# Excel is blocking chart

Tags: excel, charts

i don't know why but excel 2016 (at PC) is blocking chart in a sheet.

If i open this file on my mobile or even import to google docs charts are still there...

can someone explain me why or help?

[excel on pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JT4u.png)

[excel on mobile phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2xth.png)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried opening the file in another PC (with another office setup)? Sometimes it happens with corrupted installation. You can try repairing office as well:
https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b